# What is the "Use Trait Body" setting for?

Tags: php, netbeans

Recently I've started using PHP (worked for MS shops since graduating, and that was mostly what I used in college too). To help with this, I'm using Netbeans and am in the process of configuring it so that it's more similar to Visual Studio.

Under Options -> Editor -> Formatting, I've found this setting highlighted in the red box:

[image]

Any setting I pick for that value makes no difference in the sample file on the right. I copied the text from when I use the "Same Line" value and did a diff on it against the text when using "New Line" and they're identical.

So, what is this setting?

In the example to the right of the options, I thought this would impact the `(new Example())->alignParamsExample(...` and push anything after the `->` onto a New Line, but that's not the case.

I've also read [the documentation about traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) but I'm still unclear exactly as to what the "trait body" would be. I typed out the code they provided in "Example #2 Precedence Order Example" but noticed no behavioral difference in the IDE.

I've tagged this question with both `Netbeans` and `php` tags; if I select other languages this option isn't present (but I only have HTML, JSON, Javascript, and PHP to chose from) so I wasn't sure if this is a "PHP thing" or a "Netbeans thing." If it's explicitly one or the other, let me know and I'll remove the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is about that block in class:

```
class ExampleClass 
{
    /** Start of Use Trait Body **/
    use TraitOne;
    use TraitTwo;
    use TraitThree;
    /** End of Use Trait Body **/
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the case; If I create a second trait using the sample code in the link I provided, and the add `use SayWorld; use SayWorld2;` and hit enter it leaves them on the same line, even with "New Line" selected in the options.

Comment: Yeah, but i think it's not how single lines of use are separated but whole block from end (opening bracket) of class declaration(not sure about that one)